# .Net Maui ListView is not appearing in Android

Tags: c#, .net, listview, android-listview, maui

The problem is that listview header and content is not appearing on my android device and android emulator, so please what is the fix for that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Listv.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <ListView>
            <ListView.Header>TheHeader</ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="Hi"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: a `ListView` is naturally scrollable, there is no need for a `ScrollView` or `StackLayout`.  You have also not assigned an `ItemsSource` for `ListView` - without any data there is nothing for it to render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From above code,I found that you haven't set the `ItemsSource` for `ListView`, that is to say there is no data for `ListView` to render.

You need to set `BindingContext` for your page and set the `ItemsSource` for `ListView`.

You can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <XamListViewApp:MyViewModel></XamListViewApp:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <!--<ScrollView>-->
        <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical"
                      Spacing="25"
                      Padding="30,0"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                     >
            <ListView Grid.Row="1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
                
                <ListView.Header>TheHeader</ListView.Header>
                
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!--<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NumType}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LocationCode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Barcode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserName}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding PickingAdjustementDate}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                            </Grid>-->

                        <Label Text="Hi"/>

                    </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

    <!--</ScrollView>-->
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel() { 
     Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Items.Add( new Item { NumType = "S" , LocationCode = "0001"});
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "S", LocationCode = "0001" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });

    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
{

    public string NumType { get; set; }

    public string LocationCode { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PickingAdjustementDate { get; set; }

}
```

For more information, you can check: [ListView appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance)

**Note:**

In general, Xamarin doesn't recommend using the `ListView`, `WebView`, or `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollView`.